# How many rows are selected on an expanding table when I select all WITH (NOLOCK)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking

Imagine that I have a `foo` table in my database and every some milliseconds I am `INSERTING` new row to this table.

When run the query below:

```
SELECT *
From foo
WITH(NOLOCK)
```

And as the table is expanding continuously, how does `SQL server` decides to get how many rows of that table in the search results as I run the query with no lock?

Comment: It will select all rows including the one not committed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is unspecified behavior. NOLOCK can return all rows, can return no rows at all (yes, it can!), it can miss some rows and it can return duplicate rows. Literally, all cases are possible. In practice if the table undergoes changes (INSERTS) is very likely that you will get some missing rows and some duplicate rows with a *very* high probability. The explanation has to do with the way a nolock query scans the data (in [allocation order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/11/09/when-can-allocation-order-scans-be-used.aspx)) and how data modification moves data around (page splits on b-trees, row forwards on heaps). These data movements can move data ahead or behind the current scan point and this will result in data being ommitted (missing, when moved behind the current scan point before it was read) or data being duplicated (when moved ahead of the current scan point after it was read once, or twice even).

See [Previously committed rows might be missed if NOLOCK hint is used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) for a more detailed discussion.